# Icon showing black color rectangle in HTML

Tags: html, icons

I have created social media icons (images) using simple html code but one of the icon showing black color rectangle which covers the fb image around whereas when i see in html viewer it is perfect (no black rectnagle shown). Below is screenshot image:

https://prnt.sc/fvm0mt

I have tested by clearing cache & also in different browsers i.e: Chrome & Firefox but this rectangle is there. I have not used any command in html to show this black color rectangle. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Pls share the HTML code...

Comment: if you share your code then we can help you @Vssoft

Comment: ie next to the {} in the toolbar is the image icon!

Answer (score 0):

It may have outline css remove it. outline:none; or outline:none !important;